# How can I add commerce product automatically when saving a node 'product display'

Tags: commerce

I want to create a default product reference with the price to zero, title to node_title, sku to author_node_title. So each time I create a display product node type I haven't to fill the product reference info. If I created one display product node type -> system will create one product and auto reference that product to display product node.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a triggered rule using Rules on the event "After saving new content", creating the product entity, saving it and editing the product reference field after as well.

Comment: I tried this but didn't success. Can you share your rule for this case?

Comment: Sure thing. Check here http://pastebin.com/dnP39X4P. It's actually quite simple and you only need 2 conditions (check if the saved node is of the correct type and if it has the product reference field) and 3 actions (create the product entity, save it and set the data value of the reference field to the product you just created. Rules + Entity API is quite powerful!

Comment: Thanks for you help! I did extractly the same to you without success. Then I write a simple module for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do the opposite?
When you create a product, a display is also created.

[Commerce Bulk Product Creation](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_bpc)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, My site have a specific requirement. I want the user can post product to the site without access to admin store.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the '[Auto Product Display](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_auto_product_display)' module which simply Product Display creation process by providing option the create it at the same time with Product creation.

> Features
>
> - Provide the Product Display creation form along with the Product    creation form. User can fill that form to create Product Display at
>     the same time with Product creation.
> - That form, which used to create Product Display, will be the same as    the form when user try to create Product Display manually. So,
>     If you    have additional fields in your Product Display node type,
>     those    fields will also appear in the form.
> - If the product is referenced by only one Product Display, the Product    Display content is displayed directly to the form, so it
>     will be    automatically updated when you save the product.
> - If the product is referenced by more than one Product Display, the    referencing Product Displays will be displayed in list, so you can
>     also update the Product Display by clicking the link from that list
>     first.